# 401 Unauthorized (WebException) while posting status on Twitter from Universal app

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I want to give a feature to login to Twitter & to post Tweet from Windows 8.1 Universal app. Please don't suggest me to go for 3rd party library. I just want to do two things only. My efforts are given below. I doubt my authentication is wrong. I am getting **System.Net.WebException => The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.** What's wrong with my code, any one has idea?

```
public const string TwitterClientID = "XXXXXXXXXXXL3nZGhtKURASXg";
public const string TwitterClientSecret = "5HBuM1FVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXqaSm1awtNSes";
public const string TwitterCallbackUrl = "http://f.com";
public const string TweetFromAPI = "Tweeting from API"; 

String Oauth_token = null;
String Oauth_token_secret = null;

private async Task TwitterLogin()
{
    TimeSpan SinceEpoch = (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());
    Random Rand = new Random();
    String TwitterUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    Int32 Nonce = Rand.Next(1000000000);

    String SigBaseStringParams = "oauth_callback=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(TwitterCallbackUrl);
    SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_consumer_key=" + TwitterClientID;
    SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + Nonce.ToString();
    SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
    SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + Math.Round(SinceEpoch.TotalSeconds);
    SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_version=1.0";
    String SigBaseString = "POST&";
    SigBaseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(TwitterUrl) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(SigBaseStringParams);

    IBuffer KeyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(TwitterClientSecret + "&", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    MacAlgorithmProvider HmacSha1Provider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
    CryptographicKey MacKey = HmacSha1Provider.CreateKey(KeyMaterial);
    IBuffer DataToBeSigned = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(SigBaseString, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    IBuffer SignatureBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(MacKey, DataToBeSigned);
    String Signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(SignatureBuffer);
    String DataToPost = "OAuth oauth_callback=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(TwitterCallbackUrl) + "\", oauth_consumer_key=\"" + TwitterClientID + "\", oauth_nonce=\"" + Nonce.ToString() + "\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"" + Math.Round(SinceEpoch.TotalSeconds) + "\", oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Signature) + "\"";

    var m_PostResponse = await PostData(TwitterUrl, DataToPost, false);

    if (m_PostResponse != null)
    {

        String[] keyValPairs = m_PostResponse.Split('&');

        for (int i = 0; i < keyValPairs.Length; i++)
        {
            String[] splits = keyValPairs[i].Split('=');
            switch (splits[0])
            {
                case "oauth_token":
                    Oauth_token = splits[1];
                    break;
                case "oauth_token_secret":
                    Oauth_token_secret = splits[1];
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (Oauth_token != null)
        {

            TwitterUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + Oauth_token;
            System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(TwitterUrl);
            System.Uri EndUri = new Uri(TwitterCallbackUrl);



            WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                    WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                    StartUri,
                                                    EndUri);
            if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                var text = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.Split(new char[] { '?' })[1];

                var dict = text.Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(part => part.Split('='))
                    .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);

                //Oauth_token = dict["oauth_token"];
                //Oauth_token_secret = dict["oauth_verifier"];

                await PostTweet();
            }
            else if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
}

private async Task<String> PostData(String Url, String Data, bool flag)
{
    string m_PostResponse = null;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        Request.Method = "POST";
        if (flag)
        {
            Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
        }
        Request.Headers["Authorization"] = Data;
        if (flag)
        {
            using (Stream stream = await Request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                var postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(TweetFromAPI);
                byte[] content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postBody);
                stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            } 
        }
        HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)await Request.GetResponseAsync();
        StreamReader ResponseDataStream = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
        m_PostResponse = await ResponseDataStream.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return m_PostResponse;
}

public async Task PostTweet()
{
    Random Rand = new Random();
    Int32 Nonce = Rand.Next(1000000000);
    string status = TweetFromAPI;
    string postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(status);
    string oauth_consumer_key = TwitterClientID;
    string oauth_consumerSecret = TwitterClientSecret;
    string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
    string oauth_version = "1.0";
    string oauth_token = Oauth_token;
    string oauth_token_secret = Oauth_token_secret;
    string oauth_nonce = Nonce.ToString();
    TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    string oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

    SortedDictionary<string, string> basestringParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
    basestringParameters.Add("status", Uri.EscapeDataString(status));
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_version", oauth_version);
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", oauth_consumer_key);
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce);
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", oauth_signature_method);
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp);
    basestringParameters.Add("oauth_token", oauth_token);

    //Build the signature string
    string baseString = String.Empty;
    baseString += "POST" + "&";
    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json") + "&";
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in basestringParameters)
    {
        baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(entry.Key + "=" + entry.Value + "&");
    }

    baseString = baseString.Substring(0, baseString.Length - 3);

    //Build the signing key    
    string signingKey = Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumerSecret) +
        "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret);

    IBuffer KeyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(TwitterClientSecret + "&", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    MacAlgorithmProvider HmacSha1Provider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
    CryptographicKey MacKey = HmacSha1Provider.CreateKey(KeyMaterial);
    IBuffer DataToBeSigned = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(signingKey, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    IBuffer SignatureBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(MacKey, DataToBeSigned);
    String signatureString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(SignatureBuffer);

    string authorizationHeaderParams = String.Empty;
    authorizationHeaderParams += "OAuth ";
    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_nonce=" + "\"" +
        Nonce.ToString() + "\",";
    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_signature_method=" +
        "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method) + "\",";
    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_timestamp=" + "\"" +
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp) + "\",";
    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_consumer_key=" + "\"" +
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key) + "\",";
    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_token=" + "\"" +
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token) + "\",";
    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_signature=" + "\"" +
        Uri.EscapeDataString(signatureString) + "\",";
    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_version=" + "\"" +
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version) + "\"";

    var respo = await PostData("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json", authorizationHeaderParams, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Were did you find your callback URL *http://f.com* ?

To connect to foursquare, I'm using something like

```
var oWebBroker = Windows.Security.Authentification.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker;
var endURI = oWebBroker.getCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().absoluteUri;

...

oWebBroker.authenticateAndContinue(startURI, endURI);
```

Then, the endURI provided is something like *ms-app://s-1-15-2-26 ... 33520119519/*

Christophe

Comment: I just temporarily set `http://f.com` as `TwitterCallbackUrl`. I even tried `http://google.com`, not working. I also tried your solution, not working. I request you to try my code & find what's wrong with it.